# Registering new google.com recaptcha site with localhost:8080 raised error

Tags: vuejs2, recaptcha

For  @vue/cli 4.1.1 app I tried to register new google.com recaptcha site and got error :

```
The following domains are invalid: localhost:8080. A valid domain requires a host and must not include any protocol, path, port, query or fragment.
```

as usualy I develop @vue/cli app under localhost:8080 port(which is default).
In which way it can be salved ?

Thanks!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#im-getting-an-error-localhost-is-not-in-the-list-of-supported-domains.-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 8):

As the error says, the domain must not include any port, and the 8080 is the port number.

All you have to do is register 'localhost' - no port number - and it should work. That's what I've done and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Domains: (localhost) it will like that for loacal

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).